# how to code implication/equivalence in java

Tags: java, implication

Hello i am a beginner in coding the logic with java ,
So i wanted to know how can i code the following information. 
i have these variables in a file presented like following

example: my file.txt

```
5 1 4 
6 2 3
```

the numbers actually represent something like:

```
@1: hair = false
@2: hair = true
@3: feathers = false
@4: feathers = true
```

what i need to do,  is to code

```
{non 5 ⟺ 2 ∨ 3 } ∧{non 6 ⟺ 1 ∨ 4 }
```

in java

Now, i know that normally i should transform the ⟺ (implication/implies)to an ∨(or) but i don't how to proceed

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for these bitwise functions:

> ⟺ = xnor = !(a ^ b)
>   ∨ = or  = a | b
>   ∧ = and = a & b

```
boolean result = ((!(5 ^ 2)) | 3) & ((!(6 ^ 1)) | 4)
```

If by `non` you mean `not`, then just add a `!` where you need a negation.